# MonoMac Platform Interop with Framework

Tags: macos, frameworks, dllimport, monomac, dllnotfoundexception

I have code that uses the DllImport attribute to talk with an unmanaged assembly. In OS X, this assembly is installed as a framework.

```
[DllImport("libraryname", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void FunctionName();
```

However, this throws a DllNotFoundException in Mono, presumably because it has not been able to resolve the framework.

I looked in the Mono documentation: http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries

They have this little nugget in there:

> Mac OS X platforms have a lib prefix and a .dylib suffix, unless
>   they're a Framework, in which case they're a directory and things get
>   more complicated.

But they don't include any info (as far as I could find) about what I should do if it *is* a directory. Anyone has experience doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is pretty simple if you want to interop with a system framework as its location never changes.

For example, if you want to access the `CFRelease` function in the `CoreFoundation` framework, use:

```
[DllImport("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation", EntryPoint="CFRelease")]
public static extern void CFRelease(IntPtr cf);
```

The Mono loader will load the framework without problem.

Comment: Yeah, I played around with all the different options. Turns out I just had to do "Library.framework/Library" since the Frameworks directory is already in the search path.